# How to NOT make a selection if a condition is not met using Microsoft PICT tool?

Tags: testing

I want a state such that when FACULTY MEMBER = no, then FISCAL YEAR won't be needed (It will be in OFF state). I have used N/A as a solution but this also means that N/A is an option and thus the PICT tool will give me more results. How do I do something like, IF FACULTY MEMBER = NO, THEN IGNORE FISCAL YEAR?

```
FACULTY MEMBER:         yes, no
FISCAL YEAR:            9, 10, 11, FISCAL YEAR, N/A

IF [FACULTY MEMBER] = "NO" THEN [FISCAL YEAR] = "N/A";
IF [FACULTY MEMBER] = "YES" THEN [FISCAL YEAR] <> "N/A";
```

Comment: Hey user1562442, have you tried my solution? Can you please mark it as answer if it was helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that's not a bad practice to use "n/a" value in the list of possible parameter values (of course if it corresponds to the fact that parameter can have no value).

In your case you want to avoid setting value for "FISCAL YEAR" parameter, if "FACULTY MEMBER" is "no", right? But what should be done with the application under test in this case? I assume that "FISCAL YEAR" input field (or whatever control type you have for this parameter) will be disabled and/or default value will be automatically chosen? In this case your model is correct, since "N/A" corresponds to the absence of action.

If generated test cases with "N/A" irritates you or you simply don't need them, just filter them out and remove after you generate test-cases.

PS: in order to reduce the number of test cases which will include "N/A" option, you can also use "negative" flag in PICT, which is by default "~" in front of parameter value.

In your case the model will look like:

```
FACULTY MEMBER:         yes, no
FISCAL YEAR:            9, 10, 11, FISCAL YEAR, ~N/A

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only add a constrain as follows:

```
FACULTY_MEMBER: yes, no
FISCAL_YEAR: 9, 10, 11, NA

IF ([FACULTY_MEMBER] = "no") THEN [FISCAL_YEAR] <> "NA";
```

This generates the following (with my configuration of course):

```
/# FACULTY_MEMBER FISCAL_YEAR Notes 
1 no 10   
2 yes 11   
3 no 11   
4 no 9   
5 yes NA   
6 yes 10   
7 yes 9
```